# Loading c++ dll into c# with opencv

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, yaml, random-forest

I have build .sln code from below [github](https://github.com/usnistgov/NFIQ2) , I have import dll and try to call the initNfiq() method. when i run the build it showing below error

```
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Invalid pointer to file storage) in cvRead, file 
    C:\Users\test\Desktop\nfiq\gitrepo\NFIQ2\opencv\download\opencv-2.4.13.6\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 5002
    C:\Users\test\Desktop\nfiq\gitrepo\NFIQ2\opencv\download\opencv-2.4.13.6\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:5002: error: (-27) Invalid pointer to file storage in function cvRead

NFIQ2 ERROR => C:\Users\test\Desktop\nfiq\gitrepo\NFIQ2\opencv\download\opencv-2.4.13.6\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:5002: error: (-27) Invalid pointer to file storage in function cvRead
```

I have searched "NFIQ2 ERROR" github code i found that throwing exception on below code

```
 DLLEXPORT const char* STDCALL InitNfiq2()
  {
    try
    {
      if( g_nfiq2.get() == nullptr )
      {
#       ifdef EMBED_RANDOMFOREST_PARAMETERS
        g_nfiq2 = std::unique_ptr<NFIQ::NFIQ2Algorithm>( new NFIQ::NFIQ2Algorithm() );
#       else
        g_nfiq2 = std::unique_ptr<NFIQ::NFIQ2Algorithm>( new NFIQ::NFIQ2Algorithm("nfiq2rf.yaml", "0xccd75820b48c19f1645ef5e9c481c592") );
#       endif
        return g_nfiq2->getParameterHash().c_str();
      }
    }
    catch( std::exception& exc )
    {
      std::cerr << "NFIQ2 ERROR => " << exc.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
  }
```

Later i have added nfiq2rf.yaml file along with .exe in build folder and run the .exe That time i only got a different error like below pic

```
Initializing NFIQ2 ...
NFIQ2 ERROR => The trained network could not be initialized!
NFIQ2 is ready
```

Need some help to understand this error pls

Comment: added now.......

Comment: This isn't really related to msbuild nor C#, it's a C++ exceptions, you just have to figure out what it means. Either consult the documentation (assuming it has an explanation of what that error means), alternatively run this under the debugger and step through the code to get insight into why it fails.